# Intuition why pulling out $\mathcal{G}$-measurable $X$ of $E[f(X,Y)|\mathcal{G}]$ requires $Y$ indep of $\mathcal{G}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, intuition

Given $\mathcal{G}$ a sigma-field and $X$ a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable, on an intuitive level, why do we need $Y$ to be independent of $\mathcal{G}$ to pull out $X$ from the conditional expectation? $$E[f(X,Y)|\mathcal{G}]=E[f(x,Y)]|_{x=X}$$ I understand that if $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, it means if we know $\mathcal{G}$ we know $X$ as well so the best guess of $X$ given the $\mathcal{G}$ information is $X$ itself which makes sence. But what about the independence requirement?

Comment: The intuition comes from considering the special case $f(X,Y)=g(X)h(Y)\,.$ This will also show you that on the RHS the ${\cal G}$ goes away. That is an ordinary expectation, no longer a conditional one. And that is precisely because $Y$ is independent of ${\cal G}\,.$

Comment: The formula $E[f(X,Y)|\mathcal{G}](\omega)=E[f(X(\omega),Y)|\mathcal{G}](\omega)$ is correct if $Y$ idependent on $\mathcal{G}$ or not.
If $Y$ is also independent on $\mathcal{G}$ then $E[f(X,Y)|\mathcal{G}](\omega)=E[f(X(\omega),Y)]$

Comment: @Speltzu that $\omega$ notation is really weird. The correct one is when OP slightly corrects the RHS $$\mathbb E[f(x,Y)]\big|_{x=X}\,.$$ In my first comment I explained where that comes from, namely: $$g(X)\,\mathbb E[h(Y)]\,.$$ The reason I am being a pain in your neck is that I met someone else on MSE who insisted that $\mathbb E[f(X(\omega))]$ is correct notation for the expectation $\mathbb E[f(X)]\,.$

Comment: I don't understand: $E[f(X(\omega)]=f(X(\omega))$ depends on $\omega$, $E[f(X)]$ don´t.

Comment: @KurtG., I corrected the expression. Is it then true that $E[f(X,Y)|\mathcal{G}]=E[f(x,Y)|\mathcal{G}]|_{x=X}$ is also true even if $Y$ is not indepenent on $\mathcal{G}$? And then if $Y$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$ we can get rid of $\mathcal{G}$ because if $Y$ and $\mathcal{G}$ have nothing to do with each other then the best guess for $E[f(x,Y)|\mathcal{G}]|_{x=X}$ is the raw expectation $E[f(x,Y)]|_{x=X}$?

Comment: In the special case of $f(X,Y)=g(X)h(Y)$ I believe that $E[f(X,Y)|\mathcal{G}]=E[f(x,Y)|\mathcal{G}]|_{x=X}$ is in fact true even when $Y$ is not independent of ${\cal G}\,.$ For a general $f$ I don't have a proof but it should be similar to the one for the case in OP. This should answer your first question in that comment.

Comment: Second question: the whole point is that $\mathbb E[h(Y)|{\cal G}]=E[h(Y)]$ when $Y$ is independent of ${\cal G}\,.$ This is well known and OP is a generalization of this.

Comment: $E[f(x,Y)]|_{x=X}$, twisted notation!. Why not use $E[f(X(\omega),Y)]$ instead?

Comment: @Speltzu, I would use your notation. It is just that I get confused. For instance, you wrote $E[f(X,Y)|\mathcal{G}](\omega)=E[f(X(\omega),Y)]$ but I would write $E[f(X,Y)|\mathcal{G}](\omega)=E[f(X(\omega),Y)](\omega)$. I am not sure which one is correct : I get confused.

Comment: $E[f(X(\omega),Y)](\omega)$ does not make sense. $E[f(X(\omega),Y)]$ is not a function. It would be like writing $[f(x) ](x)$.

Comment: @Speltzu, Oh right... I get it now. Thank you for pointing this out